# Изменение формата даты несистемного времени.

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. При распарсивании xml получаю следующие данные:

```
На рынке жилья затишье

Источник: Экономика и жизнь (московский выпуск)

Дата опубликования: 25.5.2002

Вид материала: Статья
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы номер месяца в дате выводился в двухзначном формате (25.05.2002). 
Искал в инете очень долго, но находил только про изменение формата системной даты. А мне нужно изменить текущую (полученной из xml) дату, а точнее поменять только формат месяца.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
date("d.m.Y",strtotime("25.5.2002"));
```

Comment: Спасибо) Единственное, в strtotime я выводил не конкретно указанную руками дату, а значение самой переменной, отвечающей за вывод из xml даты. 
$sDateArticle = date("d.m.Y",strtotime($sDateArticle));